# Django3 Nginx Gunicorn Supervisor not logging error

Tags: python-3.x, django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

Im trying to catch/ log django errors (500) in my prod environment. However all the log files doesn't contain any traceback.

To test if it works I have a view in django with:

```
raise Exception("test exception to test the logging")
```

It doesn't matter how I change the configuration - it doesn't log it.

Current config:

Django (SETTINGS.py)

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs/django.log'),
        },
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'ERROR'),
        },
    },
}
```

prod_gunicorn.bash

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME="RPG-DJANGO"
DJANGODIR=/home/my_user/rpg-django
SOCKFILE=/home/my_user/prod_env/run/gunicorn.sock
USER=my_user
GROUP=sudo
NUM_WORKERS=4
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=rpg.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=rpg.wsgi


cd $DJANGODIR
source /home/my_user/prod_env/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --access-logfile /home/my_user/rpg-django/logs/gun_access.log \
  --error-logfile /home/my_user/rpg-django/logs/gun_error.log \
  --capture-output \
  --log-level=debug
```

/etc/supervisor/conf.d/rpg-django.conf

```
[program:RPG-DJANGO]
command=/home/my_user/rpg-django/prod_gunicorn.bash
user=root
stdout_logfile=/home/my_user/rpg-django/logs/prod_gunicorn.log
stderr_logfile =/home/my_user/rpg-django/logs/prod_gunicorn.log
redirect_stderr=true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/rpg-django.conf

```
server {
    server_name rpg.skin-society.com;

    access_log /home/my_user/rpg-django/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/my_user/rpg-django/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location = /favicon.ico {
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
        }
    location ^~  /static {
            root /home/my_user/rpg-django;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/my_user/prod_env/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

}
```